# Initiate Class and use it later within Thread creates error System.AccessViolationException

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am using a class library called DbConn to create a database connection to an access database.

I initiate 2 of that classes within a running thread like so

```
Dim thread As New Threading.Thread(Sub() saveDB(sfd.FileName))
thread.IsBackground = True
thread.Start()

Private Sub saveDB(dbpath as String) 
    Dim dbconn1 As New DbConn(databasepath)
    Dim dbconn2 As New DbConn(dbpath)
```

when I call any function from that class i get an AccessViolationException

```
Dim ds As DataSet = dbconn1.SelectCustomQuery(query)
```

If I execute the Sub directly (not within a thread) the code executes normaly without any error. Do I have to set something within the class library or within the thread. I know when I want to change UI elements I need to use delegate methods and such

Comment: Did you consider looking at the stack trace of the exception to see where the exception is actually thrown? Exceptions contain that information for good reason.

Comment: You are *trying* to use memory that hasn't been allocated just yet and that error also usually only happens when using *unmanaged* code.

Comment: But why isn‘t it allocated only when using it within a thread but not without